# Apply filter just to dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to apply a filer just to a dashboard? That is, given worksheets A and B, and dashboards X and Y that both show worksheets, can I put a filter on X that affects how A and B are *displayed* on X, but isn't actually *applied* to A and B, and thus Y is unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Filters (quick or action) applied to the dashboard will always be applied to the worksheet.

I believe you'll need to create separate worksheets for each dashboard.

Can you explain your use case a different way? i'm not fully understanding why you would want this functionality.

Comment: With this functionality, I could duplicate the dashboard, change the filter, and be done. Without it, I have to create new worksheets, apply the filter to each worksheet individually, create a new dashboard, move all the worksheets to the dashboard, and format the worksheets.